# Export table of table in csv format

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have four tables and I want to export it to a single CSV file using Python.

Here is a concrete example.
Suppose I have four tables like this:
(Maybe in array format. We can assume that all the four tables have the same shape.)

```
#table1
x11, x12, x13,
x21, x22, x23,
x31, x32, x33,

#table2
y11, y12, y13,
y21, y22, y23,
y31, y32, y33,

#table3
z11, z12, z13,
z21, z22, z23,
z31, z32, z33,

#table4
w11, w12, w13,
w21, w22, w23,
w31, w32, w33,
```

I want to export in the following format:
(I prefer csv format.)

```
x11, y11, , x12, y12, , x13, y13,   
z11, w11, , z12, w12, , z13, w12,
,,,,,,,,
x21, y21, , x22, y22, , x23, y23,   
z21, w21, , z22, w22, , z23, w23,
,,,,,,,,
x31, y31, , x32, y32, , x33, y33,   
z31, w31, , z32, w32, , z33, w33,
```

Does anybody have a good idea?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
# gets you [(['x11','x12','x13'],['y11','y12','y13']),(['x21',...],['y21',...]),...]
xy_together = zip(table1, table2)

zw_together = zip(table3, table4)


# assuming the tables are all the same length...
for i in range(len(xy_together))
    x_row, y_row = xy_together[i]
    print( zip( x_row, y_row ) )

    z_row, w_row = zw_together[i]
    print( zip( x_row, y_row ) )
```

should work.

the **zip**() function takes two or more iterables and produces a list of tuples of the corresponding elements in each iterable.